# How does this code counting the number of characters, lines, and words work?

Tags: c

```
while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN-1, infile) != NULL) {
    num_lines += 1;
    num_chars += strlen(line);
    if (strncmp(line, "", MAX_LINE_LEN) != 0) {
        num_words++;
    }
}
```

The whole program counts the number of words. This chunk of code increases the line number of text and count the words, but I don't know what's going on here. How does it work?

Comment: Is there any specific part that you don't understand?

Comment: Have you tried googling `fgets`, `strlen` and `strncmp`?

Comment: if the file exists, then increases the line number.but what does"num_chars += strlen(line);
      if (strncmp(line, "", MAX_LINE_LEN) != 0) {" these two lines mean?

Comment: "if the file exists, then increases the line number" -- Wrong. "what does ... mean?" -- You are asking very basic questions about C that are best obtained through education. SO is not a tutorial service, and flooding it with these sorts of questions is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strlen( line )
```

Give the number of characters in `line`. (Check `man strlen`.)

```
num_chars += strlen( line )
```

Add that number to `num_chars`.

```
strncmp( line, "", MAX_LINE_LEN )
```

Compare the contents of `line` with the empty string (but just to be on the safe side, do not read more than `MAX_LINE_LEN` characters of `line`, in case it is not null-terminated). Return 0 if equal. (For further details, refer to `man strncmp`.)

```
if (strncmp(line, "", MAX_LINE_LEN) != 0) {
    num_words++;
}
```

Add 1 to `num_words` if `line` does *not* equal the empty string.

Note that `num_words` is a misnomer, as there is no word counting going on here, just a counting of non-empty lines.

Comment: Can you think of a reason why not simply write `line[0] != 0`? I thought a bit and can't figure out why the author uses strncmp here.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: On second thought, there *is* a reason I could think of: This might be tutorial code, and the author wants to de-emphasize the nature of C strings being `char[]` for didactic purposes.

Comment: you got it.. it is the tutorial code, and  wants to de-emphasize the nature of C strings being char[] for didactic purposes

Comment: @Sssm: You're welcome. (Thanks is usually expressed via an upvote, and possibly an activated checkmark for "best answer".) Note that, while I am sympathetic towards tutorials encouraging solid code practices, C (and C++) derive much of their power from a culture of programmers knowing what things really *are*, underneath, and handling them as such. Ivaylo's suggestion is *much* faster in execution *and* smaller in code. Blindly following a certain practice even where better, simpler alternatives exist can get you into a tight corner when it comes to being efficient.

Comment: the second line that already add 1 to line number, why add again at the end of the code?

Comment: @Sssm: `num_lines` is counting the number of lines, empty or not. `num_words` is counting the number of *non-empty* lines. Or at least it *intends* to: The code is *seriously* broken. Not only will it result in the wrong numbers should a line exceed `MAX_LINE_LEN`; it was also written in ignorance of `fgets()` *storing the newline in the buffer*. This means that an empty line will be `"\n"` in the buffer, not `""`...

Comment: @Sssm "you got it.. it is the tutorial code, and wants to de-emphasize the nature of C strings being char[] for didactic purposes " -- How would you know this when you don't even know enough C to understand this simple bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code can be significantly simplified by writing:

```
if (line[0] != '\0') {
```

Because this is what:

```
if (strncmp(line, "", MAX_LINE_LEN) != 0) {
```

essentially does - it checks if `line` is non-empty string.

So to answer your question - after the execution of the cycle `num_words` will be equal to the number of non-empty lines in the file.